# IIS .php Rewrite 404 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble configuring PHP on my website hosted via IIS. Everything up until the point of loading and rewriting a .php extension has worked successfully.

**Detailed error report:**
[Image (Sorry I can't post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D64Jc.png)

web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3">
                    <match url="^(.*)\.htm$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 4">
                    <match url="^(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 5">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

.htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
```

I've tried many solutions to this problem and can't find anything online. Someone please help!

Comment: Running a windows 2012 VPS